# UPDATE ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100

Tags: mysql, random

I want to SET a text different for a field
I am trying  that kind of code

```
SET  @rand = 100;
UPDATE myTable SET  name = 'a'  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT @rand;
UPDATE myTable SET  name = 'b'  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT @rand;
UPDATE myTable SET  name = 'c'  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT @rand;
```

I am getting an error

> ## 1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY

thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Why are you updating by RAND(). It will slow down your update? Order by an indexed column like the primary key. This is a performance killer.

What's the point of setting @rand = 100 when you know exactly how many records you want to update in one go?

I am assuming that you have a primary key called **id**

```
update myTable set  name = 'a'  order by id desc limit 100;
update myTable set  name = 'b'  order by id desc limit 100;
update myTable set  name = 'c'  order by id desc limit 100;
```

Comment: thanks but I don't want by sorting the ID column , it should be totally RAND()
it doesn't matter if it is slow or not, I do it once

Comment: @ErickBoileau - Cool, use rand() then.

Comment: with RAND I get an error it has nothing to do with slow or not

Answer (score 1):

It works!

```
UPDATE myTable SET  name = 'a'  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100;
```

The problem was in my complex INNER JOIN.

Comment: As you excluded details of a join from your question, it is unlikely anyone would get you the correct answer. In this case would you care to edit your question and include the actual query you used? As this question and answer in its current state serves no future users

Comment: the problem was also on  SET  @rand = 100;

Comment: Even still, you haven't explained what was wrong with that?

Comment: no idea of what was wrong with SET @rand = 100;limit 100;

Answer (score 0):

I Assume you want to update a table column with the random value.You can simply do an **`update`** query for this.

```
$sql_update = "UPDATE table_name SET column_name=RAND()"
```

This will update your entire table with the rand Value.If you want to customize random Value you assign it to variable and organize.

Comment: I am not looking for a rand number , but  for different texts in the field `name`